# rails: how to supply a model with gem, and how to test rails gem without dummy app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rubygems

I have already read [The Basics Of Creating Rails Plugins](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html) and several other articles, but I can't find how to supply a model with a gem.

Say, I want to make a gem for tagging (yes, I know about [acts_as_taggable_on](http://goo.gl/il2cMF) gem, I need different functionality). So, I want the model `Tag` to be bundled in the gem. I found no tutorial explaining that.

Of course I tried to reverse-engineer acts_as_taggable_on gem to understand how does it work, but it brought even more confusion: the tutorial I mentioned above says that I should have a dummy app in my gem, in order to test the gem. BUT, acts_as_taggable_on has no such dummy application! How how does it get tested, then?

About the model: ok, I see the file `lib/acts_as_taggable_on/tag.rb` that seems to be a `Tag` model:

```
module ActsAsTaggableOn
  class Tag < ::ActiveRecord::Base
    # ..........................
  end
end
```

I see that file `lib/acts-as-taggable-on.rb` requires `tag`:

```
require "acts_as_taggable_on/tag"
```

So I've applied the same approach (assume my plugin is named dftags) :

I have added file `lib/dftags/tag.rb`:

```
module Dftags
  class Tag < ::ActiveRecord::Base
    # attr_accessible :title, :body
  end
end
```

And my `lib/dftags.rb` looks like this:

```
module Dftags
end

require "dftags/tag"
```

I have specs `tag_spec.rb`:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Tag do
  let(:tag) { Tag.new(name: "") }
  it { should validate_presence_of :name }
end
```

And when I run `bundle exec rspec spec/`, I got error `unitialized constant Tag (NameError)`.

It seems I missed something important. Plus, again, I have dummy app for testing, but acts_as_taggable_on doesn't; so, the testing approach should be different..

So, the questions:

- How can I supply a model with gem?
- How can I test my gem without dummy app?
- Are there some advanced docs about writing rails gems? Actually I tried to check out one more famous gem: [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), but the ruby-fu and rails-fu of the authors is too strong for me to understand it. Where do people learn all of it?

Comment: You probably have to describe `Dftags::Tag`...

Comment: @meagar thank you very much, that helped. My bad.. But a question about testing gems without dummy app is still relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I test my gem without dummy app?

The dummy app is only a helper that allows you to use your normal rails testing workflow when building a gem / plugin. You could run the tests without a dummy app but you would need a lot more manual work.

`acts_as_taggable_on` is pretty much `active_record` only with the exception of a single helper (as far as I can tell from a quick glance). The author therefore decided that the overhead of maintaining the dummy app was not worth the effort and is setting up `active_record` by hand. See here https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/master/spec/spec_helper.rb#L24 how he establishes the connection to the database.

This code would not be necessary when using a dummy app as rails is taking care of it.

The same is true for the helper. Instead of using the test methods provided by rails he creates a new Class that includes the helper and uses an instance of this class to test it (h/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/master/spec/acts_as_taggable_on/tags_helper_spec.rb#L11).